# What are the differences between these project types, and how can I fix the difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms, visual-studio-2015

We are in the process of migrating from VS2012 to VS2015, and I'm running into an issue with hosting one of the web projects of a different "web project" icon.

Example project types:

[image: Meeting types]

> 1 is a successfully hosted web site
>
> 2, 4, and 5 are c# class libraries
>
> 3 is a test project
>
> 6 is a website... but is clearly different than #1.  I have not successfully hosted this project at a virtual directory in VS2015, where it is in VS2012.  How is #1 different from #6?  I see #1 has a csproj file, #6 does not.  Also the "property" windows are significantly different from the project types.

1 VS2012

[image: 1 VS2012]

1 VS2015

[image: 1 VS2015]

6 VS2012

[image: 6 VS2012]

6 2015

[image: 6 2015]

As you can see the property pages of the two VSes and two different project types differ pretty significantly.

My #6 project in VS2012 is hosted at `http://localhost:9999/VirtualDirectory/` so its services can be accessed as (example):

```
http://localhost:9999/VirtualDirectory/Service1.svc
```

However in VS2015, I can't get it hosted under `http://localhost:9999/VirtualDirectory/Service1.svc` but rather only `http://localhost:9999/Service1.svc`  I've tried changing the radio button from "use default server" to "use custom server" and specifying the base URL, however the services do not resolve when attempting to host in this manner.

What is the difference between #1 and #6 project type?  What are my options for fixing my hosting differences between VS2012 and VS2015?

Right now I can change my end point connections in my web config to rather than point to `http://localhost:9999/VirtualDirectory/Service1.svc` instead point to `http://localhost:9999/Service1.svc`, but this breaks the endpoints for VS2012.  Ideally I'd like to have the project configured in such a way that it works seamlessly and without config changes between running the solution in VS2012 and VS2015.

Comment: To find specific project type names check projectTypeGuid in proj files - you can than lookup what type each particular corresponds. Than search for guid - likely you'll find the template name.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, maybe I'm just not sure where to find the ID to which you're referring.  What file is it stored in?

Comment: *.csproj - project file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 1 is a web application and 6 is a website.